# Optimization of regular expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following scenario

```
C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_P800B_RUN P800B_PUMP_RUNNING
C***************************************************

C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_VALVE_OPEN OPENING_VALVE_001
C***************************************************


C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_SIGNAL_FAIL LOSS_OF_SIGNAL
C***************************************************
```

What I intend to do is remove the `description100B` from each of these lines.
I used the following regex find and replace strings

**find:**    `(^C\s%+\s\w[A-Z\s%]+:\w[A-Z_0-9]+)\s\w[A-Z_0-9]+`
**replace:** `\1.TAG`

The end result would be like this

```
C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_P800B_RUN 
C***************************************************

C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_VALVE_OPEN 
C***************************************************


C****************************************************
C %% END MODULE %% :ALM_SIGNAL_FAIL 
C***************************************************
```

I want to know if there are better ways of doing this?

Comment: This almost seems rude, but [check here](https://regex101.com/r/oP5nE4/1), ;)

Comment: Or even this `[^*]\w+$` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/oP5nE4/2)

Comment: Why involve regex at all?

Comment: because there are lots of text in between those lines which are not shown and they have the description sprinkled everywhere. Thats why

Comment: Maybe you should update your question since `description100B` aren't even in it anymore.

Comment: I would use spaces instead of `\s` (which also matches newlines), and those `\w` aren't doing anything useful.  Also, you probably don't need to be so specific: `(^C %%.*) [A-Z_0-9]+`.

Comment: @Alan Moore. Thanks for pointing out. It's my day 1 with.complex regex. I have a long way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first one:

```
description100B
```

simply replaces your "target" with "nothing". Kind'a basic.

The second one `[^*]\w+$` replaces any "word characters" - `\w`, in a sequence (more than one `+`), **not** preceded by a `*`, with nothing.

**Edit:** Changing conditions... That's new ;)

Try

```
(:\w+)\s*\w+
```

It removes everything that comes after (what appears to be) a constant following a `:`.
[Check it here](https://regex101.com/r/oP5nE4/3).

Comment: Sorry , I was in a hurry to say that it works. Note that the descripton will change in every different instance

Comment: I agree with you **Edit** - *Changing conditions*... But your edit is right

Comment: the regex `(:\w+)\s*\w+` has done the trick. I have a long way to go in learning about regex

Comment: We all do ;) It **captures** (since inside parentheses) a sequence of characters/digits (at least one - `+`) followed by any (optional) white space and, again, followed by a sequence of char's/dig's. Replace it with what's captured, and only **that** remains.